# Sum all rows that are sum of a column sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to get a total sum of the results of my "total tested" "failed" and "passed" colums. I would usually handle these aggregates in SSRS, but I don't have that option at this time.

My current query:

```
select s.school_code, s.name, count(cd.Test_ID) as [Tested],
 sum(case when cd.result = 'fail' then 1 Else 0 End) as 'Failed'
 ,sum(case when cd.result = 'pass' then 1 Else 0 End) as 'Passed'

FROM 
 [psi_db_8amSnapshot].[dbo].[Candidate_Data] cd
  join [psi_db_8amSnapshot].[dbo].account_school s on s.school_id = cd.school_id
  where s.School_code in 
  (
  '1001', 
'1002',
'1003' ,
'1004' ,
'1005' ,
'1006' ,
'1007' ,
'1008' ,
'1016' ,
'1009' ,
'1010' ,
'1012' ,
'1013' ,
'1014' ,
'1015'
)

and cd.[date] between '01-01-2016' and '05-01-2017' and cd.TestName = 'MN Dental Assistant State Licensure Examination'
group by s.school_code, s.name, test_id
```

I am looking to get a total off all the values in my three aggregate columns. So a sum of Tested, which should = 640, sum of passed = 327, sum of failed = 313.

Comment: and this throws an error? doesn't return the right results? what?  instead of 1 pass in cd.result?  Expected results w/ sample data would go a long way to clarifying the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: This is my resulting data, it works fine. What I am trying to do is then get a total off all the values in my three aggregate columns. So a sum of Tested, which should = 640, sum of passed = 327, sum of failed = 313.

Comment: existing data return; school_code name Tested Failed Passed
1001 Central Lakes College 36 21 15
1002 Century College 136 70 66
1003 Dakota County Technical College 54 32 22
1004 Hennepin Technical College Brooklyn Park 2 1 1
1005 Hennepin Technical College Eden Prairie 56 24 32

Comment: Thanks for voting to close HABO, I added text to the question, I guess what I was looking for wasn't clear, i thought the first line explained it.

Comment: Your post translated roughly as "I want stuff. I can't use other stuff for undisclosed reasons. Here is some stuff with no context. Help." Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for group by grouping sets as below:

Just replace your group by as below:

```
group by grouping sets ((s.school_code), (s.name), (test_id))
```

Comment: Thank you, this leaves some extra data but it's a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use with statements:

```
with NumberOfFailedResults as
(
    Select count(cd.result) as NumberOfFailedResults from [psi_db_8amSnapshot].[dbo].[Candidate_Data] as cd where cd.Result = 'Failed'
),
NumberOfPassedResults as
(
    Select count(cd.result) as NumberOfPassedResults from [psi_db_8amSnapshot].[dbo].[Candidate_Data] as cd where cd.Result = 'Passed'
)

Select NumberOfFailedResults, NumberOfPassedResults, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
select Q.school_code, Q.name, SUM(Q.Tested), SUM(Q.Failed), SUM(Q.Passed) from  (   
select s.school_code, s.name, count(cd.Test_ID) as [Tested],
 sum(case when cd.result = 'fail' then 1 Else 0 End) as 'Failed'
 ,sum(case when cd.result = 'pass' then 1 Else 0 End) as 'Passed'

FROM 
 [psi_db_8amSnapshot].[dbo].[Candidate_Data] cd
  join [psi_db_8amSnapshot].[dbo].account_school s on s.school_id = cd.school_id
  where s.School_code in 
  (
  '1001', 
'1002',
'1003' ,
'1004' ,
'1005' ,
'1006' ,
'1007' ,
'1008' ,
'1016' ,
'1009' ,
'1010' ,
'1012' ,
'1013' ,
'1014' ,
'1015'
)

and cd.[date] between '01-01-2016' and '05-01-2017' and cd.TestName = 'MN Dental Assistant State Licensure Examination'
group by s.school_code, s.name, test_id)Q
GROUP BY Q.School_Code, Q.Name
```

Comment: These are actually the same results I am currently getting, what I am hoping to get is total off all the values in my three aggregate columns. So a sum of Tested, which should = 640, sum of passed = 327, sum of failed = 313. Sorry for duplicate comments, just never know if people look at previous answers.